# Swift - insert array data inside a dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, dictionary

The current data that i need to store is like this

```
var dictData = [String: [String]] () 

[groupIdKey : [key1,key2], groupIdKey2 : [key3,key4] ]
```

How to insert [key1,key2] into a particular dictionary key, and how to access every key in that dictData variable?

I'm using `Firebase` Database and here's my code

```
let groupId = self.defaults.stringArray(forKey: Constants.localDataKeys.localDataGroupId)
var addValueDict = [String: [Any]]() as NSDictionary
for group in groupId! {
    geoLocRef.child("Group").child("\(group)").child("groupMembers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if(snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]) == nil {
            print("Gada group *geolocation*")
        } else {
            let memberIdDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
            let getGroupMemberId = Array(memberIdDict.keys)
             // addValueDict["\(group)"]?.append([getGroupMemberId]) <-- My Error
        }
    })
} // end for loop NSUserDefaults
```

Comment: What is your data structure now ? You can use Dictionary's Grouping function to group. Add your data structure and on what basis you want to group them ?

Comment: Your main mistake is the bridge cast from a distinct type `[String: [Any]]` to *typeless* `NSDictionary`. Don't do that. Never do that.

Comment: The line where you get the error should be like this: addValueDict["\(group)"] = getGroupMemberId

Comment: @Starsky YEPP that's it. you can post it as answer bro. Thanks a bunch. For the next question, how do you retreive [key1,key2] according to the key without printing [ \ symbol? I can loop to the dictionary to print the values but it keeps giving me this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

Comment: Please reformulate your last question, because I don't understand what you want to achieve? You want to print the result? Or you need to store it in an array? What is it that you want to achieve? If you want [key1, key2] to be casted into 1 single String like this "key1, key2" is one thing, but if you want to just create an array with those values then it is another thing. Try to explain in details your goal.